# How to get parse columns in R and then check matching?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have df like so:

```
        GEO_ID           Area           Tot_Pop 
1 8600000US00601          ZCTA5 00601   17242  
2 8600000US00602          ZCTA5 00602   38442  
3 8600000US00603          ZCTA5 00603   48814 
4 8600000US00606          ZCTA5 00606    6437  
5 8600000US00610          ZCTA5 00610   27073 
6 8600000US00612          ZCTA5 00612   60303
```

I would like to make two new columns. One, I would like to pull the final 5 digits of the GEO_ID column to make `NewGeo`. Two, I would like to pull the string after ZCTA5 to get `NewArea`. It would look like:

```
        GEO_ID           Area           Tot_Pop   NewGeo  NewArea
1 8600000US00601          ZCTA5 00601   17242       00601  00601
2 8600000US00699          ZCTA5 00602   38442       00699  00602
3 8600000US00603          ZCTA5 00603   48814       00603  00603
4 8600000US00606          ZCTA5 00606    6437       00606  00606
5 8600000US00610          ZCTA5 00610   27073       00610  00610
6 8600000US00612          ZCTA5 00612   60303       00612  00612
```

I would then like to check if the new columns `NewGeo` matches `NewArea`, and if they don't I would like to make a new df to look at the individual columns that do not match

Comment: You have a space after `ZCTA5`, right ?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
  mutate(NewGeo = str_extract(GEO_ID, "\\d+$"),
         NewArea = str_extract(Area, "\\d+$"),
         checkEqual = NewGeo == NewArea)
```

---

Or using `mutate_at`

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(GEO_ID, Area), list(New = ~str_extract(., "\\d+$")))
```

In the new version of `dplyr`, can use `across` with `mutate`

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(c(GEO_ID, Area), list(New = ~str_extract(., "\\d+$")))
```

Comment: This is great, how do I compare the new columns to see if they are equal for every row, and if they differ, how can I look just at those rows?

Comment: @Evan You can just use `==` for the new columns created.  it would do an elementwise comparison of NewGeo and NewArea and gives a logical vector i.e. TRUE/FALSE (equal/unequal) (updated the post)

Answer (score 4):

In your case, with `data.table`, you can do

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, `:=`(NewGeo = tstrsplit(GEO_ID, "US", fixed = TRUE)[2],
          NewArea = tstrsplit(Area, " ", fixed = TRUE)[2])]
```

If you want them in numeric format, you can afterwards do:

```r
df[,c('NewGeo','NewArea') := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = c('NewGeo','NewArea')]
```

`tstrsplit` is a `data.table` built-in to efficiently cut strings. You have alternatives possible with `stringr` (not sure about this one however)

```r
df[, `:=`(NewGeo = stringr::str_split_fixed(GEO_ID, "US", simplify = TRUE)[,2],
          NewArea = stringr::str_split_fixed(Area, " ", simplify = TRUE)[,2])]
```